# Generic repository in Java

Tags: java, android, generics, dry

Let's say I have this class:

```
public class PhotoRepository  {
    private PhotoDao db;

    PhotoRepository(PhotoDao dao) {
        db = dao;
    }

    public void save(List<Photo> photos) { db.insertOrReplaceInTx(photos); }
    public List<Photo> all()  { return db.loadAll(); }
    public Photo get(Long id) { return db.load(id);  }
}
```

Since I have more kind of entities, not just Photo, I would like to have a generic Repository  where I can pass any kind of Dao.

I have tried using `Class<? extends AbstractDao<?, ?>>` as parameter of the constructor, but the compiler says that de dao methods can't be resolved. Something along these lines:

```
public class Repository<T>  {
    private Class<? extends AbstractDao<T, ?>> db;

    Repository(Class<? extends AbstractDao<T, ?>> dao) {
        db = dao;
    }

    public void save(List<T> items) { db.insertOrReplaceInTx(items); }
    public List<T> all()  { return db.loadAll(); }
    public T get(Long id) { return db.load(id);  }
}
```

I have tried with the type parameter and without it, and several other permutations, without luck.
Is there a way to do this in Java?

Thanks.

Comment: But this is not decorator pattern

Comment: What's the second type parameter for `AbstractDao`?

Comment: @kocko it's usually Long, although I've seen "?" used even in the GreenDao source code.

Comment: @bigdestroyer how come? The current methods are just shorter names for existing ones, but nothing stops me from calling several methods or doing extra stuff in them.

Comment: @haraldK even if this is a repository, isn't it a decorator, generally speaking?

Comment: @codecaster I think you would have to extend/implement `AbstractDao` for this to be a decorator (and you would use it as an `AbstractDao`). The current implementation is more a facade, creating a new simplified API on top of your DAOs. But I'm not the pattern police. ;-) I just wanted to the question to focus on what is important here, which I think is getting the generics right.

Comment: Sure, it's about the generics :) It's true that some patterns overlap, and given that I come from the ruby world, where everything is less strict, this premise is even truer, so sometimes it's hard for me to see the difference among patters like Facade, Wrapper or Decorator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to introduce a second type parameter for the `Repository` class, which will represent the dao, because `Class<? extends AbstractDao<T, ?>>` is incorrect.

Let's call this second type parameter `D`. It will always have to be a subclass of `AbstractDao`, parameterized by the type of object you want to operate with (i.e. the type `T`)

```
public class Repository<T, D extends AbstractDao<T>>  {
    private D db;

    Repository(D dao) {
        db = dao;
    }

    public void save(List<T> items) { db.insertOrReplaceInTx(items); }
    public List<T> all()  { return db.loadAll(); }
    public T get(Long id) { return db.load(id);  }
}
```

Then, you will be able to instantiate the `Repository` with:

```
Repository<Photo, PhotoDao> repo = new Repository<>(new PhotoDao());
```

Note that I'm *assuming* that `PhotoDao` is defined as:

```
class PhotoDao extends AbstractDao<Photo> { .. }
```

Comment: Great! This actually allows me to instantiate the Repository omitting the type arguments: `Repository repo = new Repository<>(daoSession.getPhotoDao());`

Comment: how can I access an inner class property of D here? In my original code I had this:

        `public QueryBuilder queryBuilder()  {
        return db.queryBuilder().orderDesc(VideoDao.Properties.Created_at).limit(10);
    }`

Comment: Although this is valid, don't do that, because this way you turn the type of `repo` to be **raw**, which drops the pros of Generics and should be avoided

Comment: As for inner class properties of `D`, you need to either do a cast, or introduce some new methods in the `AbstractDao` class, which get the properties you desire